# Post request to create an account "blocked" on node.js

Tags: node.js, postman

I have an issue with my POST request to create a user. 
When i'm testing it with postman, it stays blocked on loading. And if i cancel it, I have this in my terminal :

```
POST /users/create_account - - ms - -
```

There is the code related :

```
const client = new pg.Client({
  user: process.env.DB_DBUSER,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
})
//Third-party middelware
router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

router.post('/create_account', function (req, res, next) {
  const results = [];
  client.connect();

  // Grab data from http request
  const data = {
    username: req.body.username, name: req.body.user,
    firstname: req.body.firstname, email: req.body.email,
    location: req.body.location
  };

  // Get a Postgres client from the connection pool
  client.on('error', (err) => {
    // Handle connection errors
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ success: false, data: err });
    }

    const queryInsert = 'INSERT INTO Users(username, name,'
      + 'firstname, email, location) values($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)';
    const values = [data.username, data.name,
    data.firstname, data.email, data.location];

    // SQL Query > Insert Data into Users 
    client.query(queryInsert, values, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.stack)
      } else {
        queryInsert.on('end', () => {

          Promise.all([queryInsert])
            .then(() => client.end()).catch(err => console.log(err));
          return res.json(results);
        });
      };
    });
  });
```

Oc, in my postman body, i have that :

```
{
    "username" : "Username",
    "name" : "Bob",
    "firstname" : "Paul",
    "email" : "spfqqds@gmail.com",
    "location" : "Here"
}
```

And my dependencies :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "pg": "^6.1.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0"
  }
```

If someone can help me he/she would be my savior ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is client here

Comment: I think you might be doing the whole postgres pooling connection wrong. Assuming you are using node-postgres, see here: https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling
You are calling client.on('error'), while it looks like you should be calling that on the pool instead.
Also - it could be beneficial to state which libraries you are using and provide additional context for the code, so we know where variables are coming from.

Comment: But I need a client to make theses requests no? I mean, my client represents admin credentials.

Comment: is it throwing any error?? have you checked the console?

Comment: Oc I checked the console ^^ And no. No errors.

Comment: Pool is better indeed. Thanks @Dentych